# How can I take out digits in each string?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take out a number from each string and add 4 to each of them, but the compiler keeps telling me that:

> undefined method `captures' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

There is output 8 with the error message if I don't add `match2` and `int2` codes.

expecting output:

```
8
23
9
14
```

How can I fix this?

```
[
    "I have 4 cucumbers",
    "I've been given 19 radishes",
    "I have 5 carrots in my hand",
    "I gots 10 zucchini!"
].each do |string|

  match = /^I have (\d) ([a-z]*)$/.match(string)
  match2 = /I've been given (\d+) ([a-z]*)$/.match(string)

  int = match.captures[0].to_i
  int += 4
  int2 = match2.captures[0].to_i
  int2 += 4

  puts int
  puts int2

end
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the links, and "[mcve]". We need to know your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
 array = []
 [
     "I have 4 cucumbers", 
     "I've been given 19 radishes",
     "I have 5 carrots in my hand",
     "I gots 10 zucchini!"
 ].each do |string|
      array.push(string.scan(/\d+/))
 end

 new_array = array.flatten.map {|i| i.to_i}
 #=> [4, 19, 5, 10]

 new_array.map {|i| i.to_i + 4}   #if you want to add 4 to each element
 => [8, 23, 9, 14]
```

Comment: Instead of `each`, you could use `map` to get the array directly

Comment: I can now print the array for sure, but when I doing "array[0].to_i" and try to puts it, compiler tells me "undefined method `to_i' for ["4"]:Array (NoMethodError)" why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what your expected output should be.

Meditate on this:

```
ary = ["a 4 b", "a 19 b"]

ary.each do |string|
  string.gsub!(/\b\d+\b/) { |num| (num.to_i + 4).to_s }
end

ary # => ["a 8 b", "a 23 b"]
```

`gsub!` changes a string in place, whereas `gsub` returns the changed string. The difference would be:

```
ary = ["a 4 b", "a 19 b"]

new_ary = ary.map do |string|
  string.gsub(/\b\d+\b/) { |num| (num.to_i + 4).to_s }
end

ary # => ["a 4 b", "a 19 b"]
new_ary # => ["a 8 b", "a 23 b"]
```

Notice that `each` became `map`, because we want to return an array of changed values, and `gsub!` because `gsub`.

It's important to use `\b` when searching for numbers in strings, otherwise you can run into problems with false-positive hits affecting digits inside "words" like "foo1".

If you want to return only the values after they've been incremented:

```
ary = ["a 0 b", "a 0 b 1"]

ary.map{ |a| a.scan(/\b\d+/).map{ |i| i.to_i + 4 }}  # => [[4], [4, 5]]
```

Which, broken down, is doing this:

```
ary
.map{ |a|
  a  # => "a 0 b", "a 0 b 1"
  .scan(/\b\d+/) # => ["0"], ["0", "1"]
  .map{ |i| i.to_i + 4 } # => [4], [4, 5]
}  # => [[4], [4, 5]]
```

---

In your code you're doing:

```
match = /^I have (\d) ([a-z]*)$/.match(string)
match2 = /I've been given (\d+) ([a-z]*)$/.match(string)
```

If you're processing freeform text you can't create a match for every possible incoming string; There are infinite possibilities. Even if you're in charge of the string creation, you shouldn't need to match entire strings, only specific parts. The more you try to match, the more likely it is the code will fail.